# Countable infinite intersection of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am curious about the two results below.

I wonder why the result of the first equation does not include zero.

Additionally, please let me know the details should I use to prove the results of the second equation.

(1) $C_{k}=\{x:\frac{1}{k+1} \leq x \leq 1 \}$, then $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}C_{k}=\{ x:0 < x \leq 1 \}$

(2) $C_{k}=\{x:0 < x < \frac{1}{k} \}$, then $\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}C_{k}=\phi$

Comment: For $0$ to be in the first case there should be at least one $k$ such that $0\in C_k$, but there is no such $k$, do you see why?

Comment: For (1) notice that no $C_k$ will ever contain $0$. For (2) take $\delta>0$ you can find $k^*$ such that ${1 \over k^*}< \delta$ so that $\delta$ is not in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

For the first one suppose $0$ belongs to the union. Then $0 \in C_k$ for some $k$. Can this be possible? Use the definition of $C_k$ to show this is not the case

For the second one, suppose the intersection isn’t empty. Then some $x \in C_k$ for every $k$. Again use the definition to show this isn’t the case.